# How does Debugger.getScriptSource work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8, deobfuscation, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to run chrome debugger to gather deobfuscated JavaScripts but it returns a large number of chunks for a script. I want to know how does chrome divides one JavaScript file to multiple chunks? What exactly is one chunk of a script?

I am aware that for each script file, script tag, and eval() function separate chunks will be created. I just want to pinpoint all possible cases for which chunks are created. For example, does [lazy parsing](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/01/30/lazy-javascript-parsing-in-v8.html) also creates chunks for some functions?

It would be great if somebody can point me to some documentation about how the process works.

[Chrome debugging protocol API used](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-2/Debugger/)

Comment: This function merely [fetches a script by id](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/inspector/v8-debugger-agent-impl.cc?l=662&rcl=f212dbeaa1c0b0c97ef1d01c4cf61a2d920157b8). So the question is how V8 engine assigns an ID which you might be able to deduce from the source code.

Answer (score 7):

The [`Debugger.scriptParsed`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/v8/Debugger/#event-scriptParsed) event is what generates the `scriptId` for each script found. Each script file parsed will fire the event and should receive a unique id. As well as individual script files, each instance of a `<script>` tag within a page source will also get its own id.

There are a number of parameters the event callback gets passed. You can inspect all the arguments by logging out the `arguments` object. For example, you'll get a `url` back for a script file and `startLine` gives you the offset for `<script>` tags that appear in an HTML resource.

```
on('Debugger.scriptParsed', function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments, null, 2)(
});
```

**Investigation**

In response to your updated question, my understanding is that in debugger mode it will attempt a full parse and not to try to optimise with a pre-parse. I wasn't able to really understand the v8 code base, but I did a little testing.

I created an HTML page with a button, and a separate script file. I executed one function immediately after page load. Another function is executed on click of button.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click', () => clicked);
});
```

I inspected the output from `Debugger.scriptParsed`. It parsed the script file straight away. Upon clicking the button, there were no additional output entries. If I changed the handler to invoke the `clicked` called dynamically using `eval`, it did output a new script chunk.

```
eval('clicked()');
```

This makes sense as there's no way for the parser to know about it until it's executed. The same applies to an inline handler, e.g. `onclick="doSomething()"`

Other chunks I noticed were Chrome Extension URIs and internals URIs from chrome.

Comment: Doesn't Debugger.scriptParsed takes scriptId as a parameter? I am aware that each script file, script tag, and eval() function will be parsed into separate chunks. I just want to pinpoint all possible cases for which chunks will be created. For example, does lazy parsing also creates chunks for some functions?

Comment: No, `Debugger.scriptParsed` is an event that is triggered by V8 internals. Whereas `Debugger.getScriptSource` is a function that accepts the `scriptId` (among other parameters), so you usually invoke in the parsing callback. I've added some extra notes.